# Execute Grails custom script in _Events.groovy with Ant exec during build process

Tags: events, grails, ant, build, exec

Grails app version: 2.0.4.

I have a Grails custom script called **MyScript.groovy** in the **scripts** folder, pretty much like this:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(main: "Run my custom bash script") {
    def process = "shell-scripts/my-script.sh -d param".execute()
    process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.out)
    process.waitFor()
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

and I'm able to make it work, calling:

```
grails my-script
```

Now, I would like to execute this script in the build process, so I added the following in my **_Events.groovy** file:

```
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
    // other stuff 

    ant.exec(executable: "grails", dir: "${basedir}") {
        arg(value: "my-script")
    }
}
```

But.. if I run compilation from Intellij, the script simply gets interrupted; if I run compilation from the command line, the script hangs on for a bit with neither output nor errors, then stops. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but it seems very heavy-weight to launch Grails just to run your script, when you could just exec the script directly

Comment: That was just a way to avoid repeating the initialisation code for the bash script and the process.waitFor() call (see the first snippet). So you would go for the execution of the bash script directly, wouldn't you?

Comment: Suer, although I'd move it somewhere that both scripts can use it so it's not duplicated.